# some way to get a special key value self :: php

Tags: php, class

I have this code and I would like to obtain the value of the output `"self ::"`

```
class Main{
    
    protected static $url="";
    
    public static function url(){
        return self::$url;
    }
    
    public static function ogp(){
        $urlo =self::url(); <-- error -->
        $content = file_get_contents($urlo);
        $first_step = explode( 'og:image' , $content );
        $second_step = explode('/>' , $first_step[1] );
        $meta="<meta property=\"og:type\" content=\"website\" />\n\t";
        $meta.="<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"".self::url()."\" />\n\t";
    } 
}

Main::set("url","{$this->config["url"]}/{$url->url}{$url->custom}");
```

I would like to get the value that `shows` self::url()`;` and assign it to the variable `$urlo`

Any way to do it?

I thank you all

Comment: where's the `set` method declaration? it's not included above. it should set the static property first, then you should be able to invoke `::url()` with its value

Comment: Main::set("url","{$this->config["url"]}/{$url->url}{$url->custom}");

Comment: You didn't declare set() method. So how can you call it?